# Meaning of last "te" of saki ni itte te (先に行ってて)

Tags: nuances, colloquial-language

I always hear people saying

```
　　　先に行ってて　which means 'go ahead'
```

But I don't really understand the meaning of the last て. I know it's the abbreviation of いて but if I translate it to English, I always think like this.

```
　　　先に行っていて - Going ahead
```

So anyone can explain the latter 'te' of this sentence?

Comment: This is the same phenomenon as いましょう contracted as ましょう in [飲んでましょう](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5422).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you said, 「行っ**てて**」 is the colloquial contraction of 「行っ**ていて**」 and we almost always use the contracted form in informal speech.

There is, however, a fairly big difference in meaning between 「先に行っ**て**」 and 「先に行っ**てて**」.

「先に行って」 simply means "You go first."

「先に行ってて」 means "You go first and wait for me/us." or "You go first and I/We will follow you."

Comment: And would you respond 先に行っとくね or 先に行ってるね?

Comment: @Earthling No, that is not a natural response.  あとでね is.

Comment: @ちょこれーと Depends on the situation. 先に行っとくね would generally suggest that you will meet the other guy at the destination. 先に行ってるね is more versatile in that it can mean that you will meet the other guy either halfway somewhere or at the destination.  However, it might be different for Kansai.  I could be wrong but I feel like 行っとくね is used in both situations in Kansai.

Comment: @Tokyo Nagoya, would you be kind enough to explain the grammatical principles behind this construction in more depth, please?

Answer (score -2):

先に行ってて means "he/she" **said** he will go first. "て" means that someone said the phrase .

Comment: No, the second て is not the colloquial って, but rather a contraction of いて, as explained in the other answer.